# R - Using grouping function inside a loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, iteration, sequential

I have a set of data with group ids. Inside each group I have to do a calculation for the first observation, and then subsequently and sequentially calculate the remaining n observations in that group. I have the following data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(id = c(1:10),
       group_id = c(rep(1,5), rep(6,2),rep(8,3)),
       value1 = c(100,200,300,400,500,250,350,20,25,45),
       value2 = c(50,75,150,175,200,15,25,78,99,101)
       )


df <- df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(position = 1:n()) # Creating a position id


# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group_id [2]
     id group_id value1 value2 position
  <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
1     1        1    100     50        1
2     2        1    200     75        2
3     3        1    300    150        3
4     4        1    400    175        4
5     5        1    500    200        5
6     6        6    250     15        1
```

I would like to create an "aggregation" column, that uses value1, value2, and most importantly, the previous values in itself.
I first calculate the first step:

```r
df <- df %>%
  mutate(aggregation = ifelse(position == 1, value1 * value2, 0))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   group_id [3]
      id group_id value1 value2 position aggregation
   <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>       <dbl>
 1     1        1    100     50        1        5000
 2     2        1    200     75        2           0
 3     3        1    300    150        3           0
 4     4        1    400    175        4           0
 5     5        1    500    200        5           0
 6     6        6    250     15        1        3750
 7     7        6    350     25        2           0
 8     8        8     20     78        1        1560
 9     9        8     25     99        2           0
10    10        8     45    101        3           0
```

Then I use a loop and set the condition that if the aggregation column has 0 as a value (everything not calculated in the previous step), then I use the value1 * value2 / previous aggregation value:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$aggregation[i] <- ifelse(df$aggregation[i] == 0, round((df$value1[i] * df$value2[i]) / lag(df$aggregation)[i],0), df$aggregation[i])
}

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   group_id [3]
      id group_id value1 value2 position aggregation
   <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>       <dbl>
 1     1        1    100     50        1        5000
 2     2        1    200     75        2           3
 3     3        1    300    150        3       15000
 4     4        1    400    175        4           5
 5     5        1    500    200        5       20000
 6     6        6    250     15        1        3750
 7     7        6    350     25        2           2
 8     8        8     20     78        1        1560
 9     9        8     25     99        2           2
10    10        8     45    101        3        2272
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. I like to use `dplyr`, but so far, due to the necessity to calculate the values one after the other, I've been unable to find a good solution.

Most importantly, however, instead of the condition I use in the last portion, I would have liked to to the following:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(aggregation = case_when(
    group_id != 1 ~ value1 * value2 / lag(aggregation),
    TRUE ~ aggregation
  ))
```

However, this doesn't work in a loop. I've generally been unable to use `dplyr` inside a loop, especially since once `group_by()` is used, I feel like `mutate()` would be my only option, but it seems to create a conflict with the functionality of the loop itself.

Comment: Can't you change the ifelse-statement to `df <- df %>%
  mutate(aggregation = ifelse(position == 1, value1 * value2, value1 * value2/lag(aggregation, 1)))` and do it one step?

Comment: If I do this outside the loop, the values returned are wrong. I think since it calculates everything simultaneously in mutate(), it retains the first value taken and doesn't really iterate. Inside the loop it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `accumulate2` from `purrr`, which I think may be what you're looking for.

There are 3 arguments needed for `accumulate2`:

> For accumulate2(), a 3-argument function. The function will be passed
> the accumulated result as the first argument. The next value in
> sequence from .x is passed as the second argument. The next value in
> sequence from .y is passed as the third argument.

So, `..1` would be the accumulated result (the previous row `aggregation` value), `..2` would be `value1`, and `..3` would be `value2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(aggregation = accumulate2(value1[-1], value2[-1],
                                   ~ round(..2 * ..3 / ..1),
                                   .init = value1[1] * value2[1]) %>% flatten_dbl)
```

**Output**

```
      id group_id value1 value2 position aggregation
   <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>       <dbl>
 1     1        1    100     50        1        5000
 2     2        1    200     75        2           3
 3     3        1    300    150        3       15000
 4     4        1    400    175        4           5
 5     5        1    500    200        5       20000
 6     6        6    250     15        1        3750
 7     7        6    350     25        2           2
 8     8        8     20     78        1        1560
 9     9        8     25     99        2           2
10    10        8     45    101        3        2272
```